# Find the maximum value of the multiple variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, maxima-minima

Show that the maximum value of$$xy(z-h)\left (\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right )$$is$$\left (\frac{2}{5}h\right )^5\frac{ab}{c^4}.$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I was unable to find the stationary points

Comment: It's not true. You are missing something. Suppose you have $(x,y,z)$ that maximizes the function. Then replacing $x, y$ by $2x, 2y$ will give you a greater value.

Comment: Sorry it was -z^2/c^2

Comment: Have you heard of the gradient of a multivariable function? Set that to  $0$, solve for all the variables and then input them back into the expression.

Comment: I did that but the equations were very complex

Comment: @noorkhan My statement is still correct. Are you missing something? Like a constraint?

Comment: Nah the only other thing given is that all the constants are positive

Comment: Call your function $f(x,y,z)$. What is $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x,x,2h)$?

Answer (score -1):

Take the partial derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$, and $z$, then set them to $0$. For $x$,
$$y(z-h)\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)+xy(z-h)\frac{2x}{a^2}=0\\y(z-h)\left(\frac{3x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)=0$$
Similarly for $y$:
$$x(z-h)\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{3y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)=0$$
For $z$:
$$xy\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)-xy(z-h)\frac{2z}{c^2}=0\\xy\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{3z^2}{c^2}+\frac{2zh}{c^2}\right)=0$$
You know that $x\ne0$, $y\ne 0$, and $(z-h)\ne 0$ (otherwise the expression is zero). Then you have a simpler system:
$$\frac{3x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}=0\\
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{3y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}=0\\\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{3z^2}{c^2}+\frac{2zh}{c^2}=0$$
Subtracting the first two equations above will give $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}=\frac{y^2}{b^2}$$
Adding the first two equations yield:
$$4\frac{x^2}{a^2}+4\frac{y^2}{z^2}=2\frac{z^2}{c^2}$$
Therefore $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}=\frac{y^2}{b^2}=\frac14\frac{z^2}{c^2}$$
Now plug this expression into the third simplified equation. You will get an equation in $z$. It is quadratic, but one solution $z=0$ is not good (since that yields $x=y=0$). So it's a linear equation that will give you $z$ as a function of $h$ and $c$. Then find $x$ and $y$, and plug them into the original expression.

Comment: Assuming you do all this, why has this found the maximum point?

Comment: Because I set the derivatives to zero. It might not be a maximum, but it's a critical point. Since the function is continuous, the maxima is one of these critical points. It's easy to see that for the other critical points the value is zero or negative.

Comment: What makes you think the function has a maximum? You yourself noted it can’t, didn’t you?

Comment: I think I was wrong about that. In the original post was the wrong sign for the $z^2$ term

Comment: Well, look at my comment, then.

Comment: You are right. It must be a local maximum.

Comment: Why? Isn’t saddle point more likely?

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.